How many odd numbers with third digit 5 are there between 20000 and 69999 inclusive?
Between 20,000 and 69,999 inclusive how many odds could you find where the third digit is 5? I attempted to find, amount of odds 20,500-20,599 as an example to then find for all values. I found 50 odds. Since we need the middle digit to be 5, we have to increment by 1,000 to get the next number base. So 20,500 21,500 22,500 ..... 69,500. There are 70 such possibilities so i multiply 70 by 50 to get 3,500 ways however I don't know if this solution is correct.

$20500, 21500, 22500, \ldots 69500$ lists $50$ numbers, not $70$.

This is the same as asking in $0-49,999$ inclusive. The final digit has $5$ possibilities $(1,3,5,7,9)$, the second and fourth digits $10$ each, the third digit is fixed at $5$, and the first digits may range from $0-4$ inclusive, so $5 \times 10 \times 1 \times 10 \times 5=2500$.

Consider selecting each of the 5 digits of your number, and multiply the number of options that you have for each decision. Notably, these decisions are independent: in this problem, your choice for one digit does not constrain the possibilities for any other digit.

Digit 1: can be 2,3,4,5,6 $\implies$ 5 options
Digit 2: can each be 0-9 $\implies$ 10 options
Digit 3: Can only be 5 $\implies$ 1 option
Digit 4: can be 0-9 $\implies$ 10 options
Digit 5: can be 1,3,5,7,9 $\implies$ 5 options

As a result, the answer is
$$
5 \times 10 \times 1 \times 10 \times 5 = 2500.
$$
